# Mapping from included and excluded point topology to the usual topology

Tags: general-topology

So I'm working on this problem for topology that asks,

**Let p $\in \mathbb{R}$ and let $l_p$ and $\epsilon_p$ be the included-point topology and the
excluded-point topology based at $p$.**

**(1) Which maps from $(\mathbb{R}, l_p)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{usual})$ are continuous?**

**(2) Which maps from $(\mathbb{R}, \epsilon_p)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{usual})$ are continuous?**

For the included point topology, there are no disjoint non-empty open sets, so every continuous function that maps to the real line must be constant, which would imply that every map between this topology and $\tau_{usual}$ would be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Is this correct and how would I go about getting the continuous maps from the excluded point topology? Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Didn't check it completely now, but I think in both cases only constant functions are continuous. Look at $f(p) =: q$. Then you either consider the preimage of $q$, which must be a closed set which contains $p$ or you look at preimages of arbitrarily small open sets containing $q$ which have to be open and contain $p$.

Answer (score 3):

For any pair of spaces, the constant maps are always continuous.

If $f: (\Bbb R, I_p)$ to standard reals is continuous, and it has two values or more, then we find disjoint open subsets $U,V$ around two image points and then $f^{-1}[U]$ and $f^{-1}[V]$ are disjoint non-empty and open, which cannot happen in any included point topology. So *only* the constant maps are continuous. We only need that the standard reals are Hausdorff for the argument to work.

If $f: (\Bbb R,\epsilon_p)$ to standard reals is continuous, and we have two values $f(x) \neq f(y)$ then $F_x=f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}]$ and $F_y=f^{-1}[\{f(y)\}]$ are disjoint closed non-empty sets, which cannot happen in any excluded point topology (all closed sets that are non-empty contain $p$). So *only* the constant maps are continuous. We only use that the standard reals are $T_1$ for this argument to work.