# Understanding continuity argument

Tags: general-topology

[Mapping from included and excluded point topology to the usual topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553974/mapping-from-included-and-excluded-point-topology-to-the-usual-topology)

Here below is my understanding of what @Henno Brandsma wrote in the link above. Do I understand the answer correctly?

Let $p \in f^{-1}[U]$. Since $f^{-1}[U] \cap f^{-1}[V] = \varnothing$, we have $p \not \in f^{-1}[V]$ and so $f^{-1}[V] \not \in I_p$ meaning $f$ is not continuous.

We have that $F_x, F_y$ are $\tau_{usual}$-closed. Suppose some arbitrary $G$ is $\epsilon_p$-open. Then $p \not \in G$. If $p \in G$, then $G$ is $\epsilon_p$-nonopen or $G$ is $\epsilon_p$-closed. Since $p \not \in F_x, F_y$, it follows $F_x, F_y$ are $\epsilon_p$-open meaning $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: $F_x$ lives in the domain so is not $\tau_{\text{usual}}$ closed, it’s $\epsilon_p$ closed if $f$ is indeed continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All non-empty open sets in $I_p$ contain $p$. $f^{-1}[U]$ and $f^{-1}[V]$ are both non-empty and nevertheless disjoint (and of course open if $f$ is continuous) so this cannot be. That’s the crux of the first case. What you say is also true but put more complexly IMO.

And in the excluded topology wrt $p$, we have a symmetric argument but using closed sets instead. All non-$X$ closed sets contain $p$ (as the complement is open and non-empty and so does **not** contain $p$) and so cannot be disjoint at all. But if $f$ is continuous and $f(x) \neq f(y)$ where $x \neq y$, then $F_x:=f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}]$ is closed and contains $x$ and the similarly formed set $F_y$ from $y$ is also closed and contains $y$ and they are disjoint and both non-$X$. This is the contradiction. The arguments are sort of mirror images in a way.

What you’re saying about $\epsilon_p$ makes no sense to me and is *not* what I said.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, Is the following correct w.r.t. $\epsilon_p$? Suppose there are $f(x), f(y)$ in the image of $f$ s.t. $f(x) \ne f(y)$. Then $\{f(x)\}, \{f(y)\}$ are closed in $\tau_{usual}$. If some $G \in \epsilon_p$, then $p \not \in G \iff p \in \mathbb R \setminus G$ meaning only closed sets in $\epsilon_p$ contain $p$. That means $f^{-1}\{f(x)\}, f^{-1}\{f(y)\}$ are open in $\epsilon_p$ and so $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: @user947160 No, it makes no sense to talk about some $G$. Just note that **if** $f$ is continuous $F_x$ and $F_y$ are closed disjoint and not $X$. QED. Why complicate things?

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, ok. $G$ is just an aid for me(cause I still keep forgetting to invoke complements). Anyway, $\{f(x)\}, \{f(y)\}$ are closed in $\tau_{usual}$. But $f^{-1}\{f(x)\}, f^{-1}\{f(y)\}$ are open in $\epsilon_p$. Contradiction. Took me a bit to realize that. This is all I needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: @user947160 In general spaces open does not contradict closed, as sets can be both!! So I use an argument adapted to the topology at hand…